# test if two characters contain same letters regardless of order in R

Tags: r, regex

Lets say I have several characters vectors of 1L. The elements on either side of the `-` will always be together in that order and the pairs will always be inverses of each other eg (1-2, 2-1). I want to return TRUE for duplicate pairs regardless of order.

```
a <- "abc-def"
b <- "def-abc"
d <- "abc-ghi"
```

here is my solution so far. I split the strings, sort them, and then paste them together. This allows me to use `all.equal()` to see where the pairs match.

```
a1 <- paste(sort(strsplit(a,"-")[[1]]), collapse = "-")
b1 <- paste(sort(strsplit(b, "-")[[1]]), collapse = "-")
d1 <- paste(sort(strsplit(d, "-")[[1]]), collapse = "-")

all.equal(a1,b1)

all.equal(a1,d1)
```

But this feels very manual. Is there a way to directly compare a to b and a to d without the manipulation I did above?

Edit:
Ideal output would be unique strings regardless of order.

Comment: How are you creating these strings?  This could be generalized quite easily if you're able to store the strings in a vector or a list quite easily.

Comment: `lapply(strsplit(c(a,b,c), '-'), sort)`

Comment: Mabe skip the `paste`: `a1 <- strsplit(a,"-")[[1]]; b1 <- strsplit(b,"-")[[1]]; d1 <- strsplit(d,"-")[[1]]` and use `match` and `sum`: `sum(match(a1, b1, 0)) == 3; sum(match(a1, d1, 0)) == 3` ?

Comment: Or using `sub` and `grepl`: `grepl(sub("([^-]*)-([^-]*)", "\\1-\\2|\\2-\\1", a), b)` `grepl(sub("([^-]*)-([^-]*)", "\\1-\\2|\\2-\\1", a), d)` ?

Comment: what's your expected result? You need a comparing function? You need to get unique strings? You need to flag duplicates?

Comment: @Dason the strings are already created and stored in a column in a data.frame before they get to me

Comment: @Edo I will update my question but I need to get unique strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like speed matters. `strsplit` returns a list and iterating over list elements is typically slower than vertorizing. So convert the list from `strsplit` as soon as possible to vectors:

```
. <- matrix(unlist(strsplit(c(a,b,d), "-", TRUE)), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
#. <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(c(a,b,d), "-", TRUE)) #Alternative
i <- which(.[,1] < .[,2])
unique(rbind(.[i,], .[-i,2:1]))
#     [,1]  [,2] 
#[1,] "abc" "def"
#[2,] "abc" "ghi"
```

Or avoid using `strsplit` and use instead `regexpr` and `substr`:

```
s <- c(a,b,d)
i <- regexpr("-", s, fixed=TRUE)
. <- data.frame(a = substr(s, 1, i-1), b = substring(s, i+1))
i <- which(.[,1] < .[,2])
unique(data.frame(a = c(.$a[i], .$b[-i]), b = c(.$b[i], .$a[-i])))
#    a   b
#1 abc def
#3 abc ghi
```

The same but using `sub`:

```
s <- c(a,b,d)
. <- data.frame(a = sub(".*-", "", s), b = sub("-.*", "", s))
i <- which(.[,1] < .[,2])
unique(data.frame(a = c(.$a[i], .$b[-i]), b = c(.$b[i], .$a[-i])))
```

Or using `read.table`:

```
. <- read.table(text=c(a,b,d), sep="-")
i <- which(.[,1] > .[,2])
x <- .$V1[i]
.$V1[i] <- .$V2[i]
.$V2[i] <- x
unique(.)
```

---

Benchmark

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e5
s <- apply(matrix(sample(letters, 300L*3L, TRUE), 3), 2, paste, collapse = "")
s <- apply(matrix(sample(s, n*2, TRUE), 2), 2, paste, collapse = "-")

bench::mark(check=FALSE,  min_iterations = 7,
TimTeaFan = unique(as.data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(s, "-"), sort)))),
strsplitRbind = {. <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(s, "-", TRUE))
i <- which(.[,1] < .[,2])
unique(rbind(.[i,], .[-i,2:1]))},
strsplitMatrix = {. <- matrix(unlist(strsplit(s, "-", TRUE)), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
i <- which(.[,1] < .[,2])
unique(rbind(.[i,], .[-i,2:1]))},
substr = {i <- regexpr("-", s, fixed=TRUE)
. <- data.frame(a = substr(s, 1, i-1), b = substring(s, i+1))
i <- which(.[,1] < .[,2])
unique(data.frame(a = c(.$a[i], .$b[-i]), b = c(.$b[i], .$a[-i])))},
sub = {. <- data.frame(a = sub(".*-", "", s), b = sub("-.*", "", s))
i <- which(.[,1] < .[,2])
unique(data.frame(a = c(.$a[i], .$b[-i]), b = c(.$b[i], .$a[-i])))},
read.table = {. <- read.table(text=s, sep="-")
i <- which(.[,1] > .[,2])
x <- .$V1[i]; .$V1[i] <- .$V2[i]; .$V2[i] <- x
unique(.)}
)
```

Result

```
  expression          min   median itr/se…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total_…⁴
  <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>    <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:tm>
1 TimTeaFan         1.17s     1.2s    0.829  15.5MB    19.6     7   166    8.45s
2 strsplitRbind  209.79ms  298.7ms    3.08   15.7MB    13.2     7    30    2.27s
3 strsplitMatrix 185.27ms  295.3ms    3.48   17.2MB    11.4     7    23    2.01s
4 substr          79.46ms  117.5ms    6.44   16.2MB    12.9     7    14    1.09s
5 sub            116.95ms  138.5ms    7.06   13.2MB    14.1     7    14 990.98ms
6 read.table      81.02ms   89.4ms    9.13   15.6MB    17.0     7    13 766.48ms
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your desired output is. A vector with `TRUE`, `FALSE`? Or all duplicate / unique strings. For the later we can build on the approach outlined by @onyambu in the comments and get a matrix, and then transform into a data.frame that we can work with:

```r
# put sorted strings in data.frame
dat <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(c(a,b,d), "-"), sort)))

# show unqiue strings
unique(dat)
#>    V1  V2
#> 1 abc def
#> 3 abc ghi

# show duplicate strings
dat[-as.numeric(rownames(unique(dat))), ]
#>    V1  V2
#> 2 abc def
```

Data from the OP

```r
a <- "abc-def"
b <- "def-abc"
d <- "abc-ghi"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>